# Asincrónico Angular

Tags: angular

Hola chicos tengo este problema en mi servicio de angular...el servicio se comunica con el api de spotify para hacer esta comunicacion antes tengo que solicitar un token...(todo venia sirviendo hasta que intente hacer esto) cree la app pidiendo el token desde postman e insertandolo manualmente en el code y cambiandolo cada que expiraba, entonces ahora uso un server de nodejs para pedir el token a spotify y usarlo en mi app.... PERO NO SIRVE...

Anteriormente habia publicado un code que tenia un error humano(pense que podia hacer un return dentro de un subscribe), en este ya solucione eso pero no logro hacer que sea asyncrono porque necesito que me ponga primero la variable token antes de ejecutar el `getNewReleases()`

lo que intenta hacer mi code => llmar la function getToken esta le da valores al token que va a servir para ser enviado a la api de spotify despues desde el component se llama el metodo getNewReleases desde el ngOnInit()

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyService {
  
  constructor(
    private _http:HttpClient
  ) { 
    this.getToken();
  }
  token: string;
  tokenType: string;
  getQuery(query: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/${ query }`;
    let bearer = this.tokenType+' '+this.token;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', bearer);
    console.log(headers);
    return this._http.get(url, { headers });
  }

  
  getNewReleases() : Observable<any>{
    

    return this.getQuery('browse/new-releases?limit=20')
              .pipe( map( data => data['albums'].items ));
      

  }
  getArtists(term:string):Observable<any>{
    return this.getQuery(`search?q=${term}&type=artist`)
      .pipe(map((data:any)=> data.artists.items));
   
  }
  getArtist(term:string){
    return this.getQuery(`artists/${term}`);
   
  }
  getTopTracks(term:string){
    return this.getQuery(`artists/${term}/top-tracks?country=US`)
      .pipe(map(data=> data['tracks']));
  
  }
 async getToken(): Promise<any>{
    const clientSecret  = '764b7c064b8490fa10f50f2a3450028';
    const clientId = '567b16bdfd23132942483002be41bc0';
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/spotify/';    
  let prom =  await this._http.get(url + `${clientId}/${clientSecret}`).toPromise().then((data:any)=>{
    this.token = data.access_token;
    this.tokenType = data.token_type;
  })

    
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
 async   ngOnInit() {
  this.error=false;
  this.loading =true;

await this.spotifyService.getNewReleases().subscribe((data:any)=>{
    console.log("comp"+data);      
    this.newSongs= data;
    this.loading=false;
  },(err:any)=>{
    console.log("error component");
    this.error=true;
    this.loading=false;
    this.errorMsg = err.error.error.message;
  });
 
  
  }
```

Comment: Has complicado demasiado tu codigo para recibir un token, lee la documentacion de spotify y de angular para solucionar tu problema, es más facil de lo que imaginas

Comment: quiero creer que ese clientsecret no es real no? si lo es, avisame urgentemente porque no deberia estar a plena vista aca!

Comment: client_secret no es real

Comment: Tomasz es que no quiero que el usuario utilize sus credenciales quiero solo usar mis client_id y client_secret